# Copy all files to another location

Tags: linux, shell-scripting, cp

I have a folder called "employee" and within that folder there are sub-folders with each employee name.

```
employee
>> amar
>> akbar
>> anthony
```

Each of these folders contain 1 or 2 files. There are around 50 employees. I want to copy all those files into a new folder "/home/employee_files" without the sub-folders. In other words, all the files should be available when I list "ls /home/employee_files"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cp employee/*/* /home/employee_files/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find /home/attachments/ -type f -exec cp {} /home/attachments_all/ \;
```

Beware that if two files have the same name, you'll only end up with one of them.

An alternate approach is to copy files to a name that is a hash of their contents.

```
#!/bin/bash
cp "$1" /home/attachments_all/`sha1sum "$1" | cut -f 1 -d ' '`
```

That will give you a unique copy of each file regardless of what it was named before. You can alter the script to provide you an index file.

Answer (score -2):

```
find /home/attachments/ -name "*.*" -exec scp {} /home/attachments_all/ \;
```

Comment: Because, of course, all files have a period in them, but a directory *never* would...